# Adding a progress bar behind a floating div in a li element

Tags: html, css

I am designing a very basic file listing layout in HTML and CSS. Although its working but I would like to know if the following code could be improved upon so that its more good and follows the best practices. I am looking forward of supporting I.E 9+ too. Plus I would like to add a progress bar behind the `left-wing`. In other words I would like to show download progress behind the filename and time as a whole.

I am showing only the part I would like to review.

**HTML**

```
<div id="list-content">
    <ul id="file_list">
        <li>
            <div class="f_icon"><img src="images/Docs-icon.png"></div>
            <div class="left_wing">
                <div class="f_name">File name Short and loooooooooooong.ext</div>
                <div class="f_time">Sep 08, 2016</div>
            </div>
            <div class="right_wing">
                <div class="f_delete"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-align-center" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                <div class="f_size">34.50 MB</div>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li>
            <div class="f_icon"><img src="images/Docs-icon.png"></div>
            <div class="left_wing">
                <div class="f_name">File name Short.ext</div>
                <div class="f_time">Sep 08, 2016</div>
            </div>
            <div class="right_wing">
                <div class="f_delete"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-align-center" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                <div class="f_size">34.50 MB</div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#list-content
{
    margin:auto;
    margin-top: 5%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: absolute;
    width: 90%;
    height: calc(95% - 105px);
}
#file_list
{
    width: 100%;
}
#file_list li
{
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
}
.f_icon
{
    width: 10%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
.f_icon img
{
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    display: block;
}
.left_wing
{
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
.f_name
{
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.f_time
{
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-style: italic;
    color: cornflowerblue;
    padding-top: 2px;
}
.right_wing
{
    width: 40%;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 6px;
}
.f_size
{
    float: right;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.f_delete
{
    float: right;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    color: #B10002;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 4px;
}
```

**PROBLEM**

For the progress bar I had tried something like the code below but it seems that padding of the overlying text and the progressbar doesnt look good **plus** `width: 50%;` **doesn't seem like 50%**.

**HTML**

```
<div class="left_wing">
    <div class="progressbar"></div>
    <div class="f_name">File name Short and loooooooooooong.ext</div>
    <div class="f_time">Sep 08, 2016</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.progressbar
{
   height: 30px;
   position: fixed;
   width: 50%; /*Testing purpose only*/
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like that ?

```css
#list-content {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 5%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: absolute;
  width: 90%;
  height: calc(95% - 105px);
}
#file_list {
  width: 100%;
}
#file_list li {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
}
.f_icon {
  width: 10%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}
.f_icon img {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  display: block;
}
.left_wing {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
.f_name
{
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.f_time
{
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-style: italic;
    color: cornflowerblue;
    padding-top: 2px;
}
.f_name,
.f_time {
  z-index: 3;
  font-size: 1em;
}
.progressbar {
  height: 3.2em;
  position: absolute;
  top: -0.1em;
  left: -0.1em;
  animation-name: load;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  background: lightgray;
  z-index: -1;
  /*Testing purpose only*/
}
@keyframes load {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="list-content">
  <ul id="file_list">
    <li>
      <div class="f_icon">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9a/Gull_portrait_ca_usa.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="left_wing">
        <div class="progressbar"></div>
        <div class="f_name">File name Short and loooooooooooong.ext</div>
        <div class="f_time">Sep 08, 2016</div>
      </div>
      <div class="right_wing">
        <div class="f_delete"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-align-center" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="f_size">34.50 MB</div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: hopefully. I can confirm after I try the css or you show me with some images and all.

Comment: i made an animation so you can see it better

Comment: Ok, it's almost what I was looking but it seems that you have no longer used `ellipsis`. But it's what I require too for the filenames as they may be too long and I don't want them to wrap to next line.

Comment: My each thread should be: Image to the left. Beside that filename and time should be stacked upon each other(height of the stack should match height of the image). Beside that file size and beside that delete button.

Comment: ok i added it but i changed almost nothing on your code exept of left_wing and progessbar class

Comment: Yes its the thing. For verifying the image positioning can you add a small image to the left where the image is missing.

Comment: Here you go. ^^

Comment: Great! Thanks.. ^_^ I am checking you green. Incase I need some help with this I will comment here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123047/discussion-between-ayan-and-rudi-urbanek).